# Which is better jodatime or prettytime

Tags: java, date, time, jodatime, period

for those who have worked with time handling libraries, I want to ask wich is best (jodatime or prettytime).

I'm working on an application that requieres mainly, calculating how many days (or months or minutes according to the lenght of the period) have past since a specific date.

So, wich one of these libraries should I use? in your experience which is better? which is easier? should I check for another specific library?

Thanks a lot.

PD. there's no tag for prettytime, that's why I just use jodatime tag.

Comment: Make your proof of concept about both, then choose the best for your needs/requirements.

Comment: I asked this question looking for specific experise... didn't ask for a debate, just facts from people who have used some of both libraries to help me take a decision. but... whatever.
This comment is for closers.

Answer (score 3):

They are very different libraries. For dateTime Managment (switching between calender types, calculating duration etc. ) Joda Time is your library. For human readable time formats ("5 minutes ago") you would use prettyTime. I actually use Jdoa time in my web apps and moment.js for formatting.